# separate out specific information in a cell in Excel

Tags: concatenation

I have received data in Excel from a 3rd party.
They have included all the data in the one cell
I want to separate out some information to get the customer code:

*E.g:  All this is in one cell and I want to extract the first 9 digits before the first # symbol

```
TRANSPORT LIMITED         Name    Address               052596690#200423R055#000000000605489              144637203                    1        2019-08-27844989                              B00000008670S                    0000000000000000000000*
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work

Data > Text to Columns > Deliminated > Other (then write in # in the box)